# preg_replace_callback error

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following code on my WordPress install:

```
function add_glossary_links($content) {
    global $wpdb, $wordlist;
    if ( !$wordlist && !$wordlist = get_option('wordlist') ) {
        mysql_query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000');
        $wordlist = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT post_title SEPARATOR "|") AS list FROM '.$wpdb->posts.' WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="glossary" AND post_parent>0');
        add_option('wordlist', $wordlist);
    }

    $wordlist = str_replace(array(" ", "'", "."), array("\s", "\'", "\."), $wordlist);
    echo $wordlist;

    $content = preg_replace_callback(
        '/\b('.$wordlist.')\b/i',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return "<a href=\"/glossary/" . strtolower(substr($matches[0],0,1) . "/" . $matches[0]) . "/\">" . $matches[0] . "</a>";'
        ),
        $content
    );

    return preg_replace('/(<[^<]+)<a\s.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/si','$1$2', $content);
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_glossary_links' );
```

The idea is that I get a list of words from my database; if they exist I replace them with links to the appropriate glossary term.

`$wordlist` is echoing out as this: http://pastebin.com/6XnWBJwM

The error that I'm receiving is this:

`Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Unknown modifier 'c' in /my.website/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 384`

Line 384 is the last line of this segment:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
        '/\b('.$wordlist.')\b/i',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return "<a href=\"/glossary/" . strtolower(substr($matches[0],0,1) . "/" . $matches[0]) . "/\">" . $matches[0] . "</a>";'
        ),
        $content
    );
```

I presume there's a problem with the formatting of the regexp and the way the wordlist is displaying but I can't for the life of me fathom it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because one of the words has a `/` in it, which is being interpreted as the end delimiter. Anything after is then interpreted as modifiers, and "c" isn't valid as one of those.

You should run the input through [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg-quote), however since you are concatenating the values in your query this won't work out of the box.

I suggest not using `GROUP_CONCAT`, instead getting each word on its own row. Then, take the rows and fill an array with the words. Last, use `implode("|",array_map("preg_quote",$words,array_fill(0,count($words),"/")))` and put that in your regex.

Comment: Note that `preg_quote()` without the second argument won't escape `/`.

Comment: I'm using GROUP_CONCAT because it was suggested to me for speed purposes - the list is derived from 1,750 rows in the database. Is there any other way around it without changing the SQL?

Comment: Well, you *could* just use `str_replace("/","\\/",$wordlist)`, but bear in mind that you leave yourself open to injection if any of those words can be user-submitted (or any of them contain other regex-specific characters)

Comment: Glossary entries are written by author-level users in the admin area. Could I sanitise the data before it goes into the database, then run a `str_replace` as you're suggesting? Is there a list of other regex characters that would need escaping? Any idea what kind of speed impact a str_replace would have on ~1700 entries?

Comment: You can certainly run `preg_quote` on input data before it gets saved, yes. I would suggest running a single-use code that takes all the words, runs them through `preg_quote`, then puts the result back in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `$wordlist` through [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

```
$safeWordlist = implode('|', 
                    array_map(function($word) { return preg_quote($word, '/'); }, 
                    explode('|', $wordlist))
                       );
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PmkibZ).

Don't roll your own escaping method :)

Comment: Hi Alex. Yeah I meant to remove the `str_replace` as it was just me mucking about trying to fix things. Will your code have an impact on speed when used with ~1750 entries in the array?

Comment: @dunc Possibly. You should also watch for the limit of the regular expression. It's limited to 65k from memory.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how I can get around this then? It needs to be as quick as possible really. More information available from my OP on WPSE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41667/