# PHP regex: take a string list, search some content, replace any matches from list with a link

Tags: php, regex

I have a very large list of terms such as this (around 1600 entries, maybe 2000 words): http://pastebin.com/6XnWBJwM

I would like to search my `$content` for the terms in this list, and replace any that are found with a link following this format: `<a href="/glossary/firstinitial/term">term</a>` such as (term: abdomen) `<a href="/glossary/a/abdomen">abdomen</a>`.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302605/) thread, I've been using `preg_replace_callback` but can't get it to work correctly - it's currently linking every single word in the content to "/"! I'm very poor with regex!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to change e.g. **abdomen** into `<a href="/glossary/a/abdomen">abdomen</a>` here's a suggestion:

```
$terms = 'abdomen|etc|parental care';
// this is the string of the terms separated by pipes

$terms = explode('|',$terms);
// split terms into an array (aka $terms)
foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {
    $terms[$key] = preg_replace('/\s\s*/',' ',strtolower($value));
}
// change each into lowercase and normalize spaces

$str = 'Here\'s some example sentence using abdomen. Abdomen is a funny word and parental care is important.';

foreach ($terms as $term) {
// this will loop all the terms so it may take a while
// this looks like a requirement because you have multi-word terms in your list
    $str = preg_replace('/\b('.$term.')\b/i', '<a href="/glossary/'.$term{0}.'/'.str_replace(' ','%20',$term).'">$1</a>', $str);
    // regardless of case the link is assigned the lowercase version of the term.
    // spaces are replaced by %20's
    // --------------------
    // ------- EDIT -------
    // --------------------
    //   added \b's around the term in regex to prevent, e.g.
    //   'etc' in 'ketchup' from being caught.
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Check the last comments in code.

Comment: it's another approach, but the problem with this code is that when you change the href of the 'a' tags you must re-code the preg-replace instead of making it to be not so much html-specific.

Comment: Thanks for this inhan. However, with so many words, will this have a detrimental impact on the loading of my page?

Comment: @inhan $str = preg_replace('/('.$term.')/i', '<a href="/glossary/'.$term{0}.'/'.str_replace(' ','%20',$term).'">$1</a>', $str);
 if he changes in the html the link string to let's say... "<a href="/gloss/somewhat" he must come to the code and correct it... nothing bad :) but tedious. That's why i said to be not so html specific creating the regex.

Comment: @dyoser: What is the other option while inputting extra content unless (or actually even if) it is bound in a function? For example how would you change **etc, Etc, …** into `"<a href="/gloss/etc">etc</a>` anyway without explicitly writing the desired format in your code?

Comment: @dunc: I'm not sure, you might wanna try and see.

Answer (score 2):

```
// the list of words
$words = explode("|",$arrayOfWords);

// iterate the array
foreach($words as $c=>$v)
 // replace the word in the link with the item of the array
 $line = preg_replace("|<a\w+>(.*)</a>|Usi",$v,$string)
```

There're too many ways of create the reg and parse it... all valids.